# Forms LoginUrl - how do I format this to work with an area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have added an Area to my Web project wherein I hope to perform all the necessary authentication tasks.  The folder structure in the project is:

```
- Solution
  - Web Project
    - Areas
      - Accounts
        - Controllers
            AccountController.cs
```

In the `AccountController` is the usual `LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)` Action.

In the `AccountsAreaRegistration.cs` is the auto-generated route:

```
context.MapRoute(
   "Accounts_default",
   "Accounts/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   new { 
       action = "LogOn", 
       id= UrlParameter.Optional 
   }
);
```

The first thing that occurred to me was to simply add the name of the area to the `loginUrl` attribute in the web.config, and let the route mapping take care of the redirect - pretty simple, I thought:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Accounts/Account/LogOn"
       timeout="2880" />
```

The only problem is that it doesn't work.  I get an error saying "unable to find "/Accounts/Account/Logon" - or whatever value I put in the loginUrl attribute.  It seems to me that the URL I specify in the Web.Config isn't pushing that value through the route table to look for a match.

*note:  all of this is being triggered by an [Authorize] attribute on an action in one of my other controllers.

**EDIT**

The workaround I have found is to leave the URL as the default ("Account/Logon") and add another route in the global.asax to redirect the request to the right area:

```
routes.MapRoute("LogOn",
                "Account/LogOn/{id}",
                new { controller = "Account", 
                      action = "LogOn", 
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional}
).DataTokens.Add("area", "Accounts");
```

This gets the job done, but I don't know if it's the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I have found is to leave the URL as the default ("Account/Logon") and add another route in the global.asax to redirect the request to the right area:

```
routes.MapRoute("LogOn",
            "Account/LogOn/{id}",
            new { controller = "Account", 
                  action = "LogOn", 
                  id = UrlParameter.Optional}
).DataTokens.Add("area", "Accounts");
```

This gets the job done, but I don't know if it's the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the controller action you're testing tagged with the [Authorize] attribute?

Which part isn't working, the authorization of some action or the routing to the logon action after requesting an authorized action?

Comment: @ScottSEA
In your global.asax.cs, do you have a call to:
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
([link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.arearegistration.aspx)